# How to select an option from Select box using arrow keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, drop-down-menu

I have tried with `.change()` and/or with `.select()`, even with `.click()`, but no hope.

When I stop on a select box field with a Tab-focus, and when I press up or down I'd like that currently focused option item to be selected instantly.

Is it possible to achive this with jQuery/JavaScript?

Comment: Trap key events (in addition to other input events, so as to not exclude them)?

Comment: @TimMedora: it won't work... how'd you determine which item in the select list is currently being FOCUSED?

Comment: you could track the state of the currently selected option in an external array, then set the appropriate option on each `keyup` ...

Comment: @Xander: do you have any examples please?

Comment: no code handy, but what i wrote should be enough for you to get on your way ...

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding the problem/requirement. This is what I came up with; perhaps you should modify it to indicate what you would want it to do, and what's not working: http://jsfiddle.net/m8KcS/1/

Comment: I have found a solution for this, and it's more easy than I tought... I'm gonna post an answer for this

Comment: Browsers already allow navigation of options using the cursor keys, why is script needed? Tab to the select, use the cursor keys to select an option, then tab (or click somewhere else) to move focus and the option is selected. A change event may be dispatched when an option is selected (IE model) or when the selected option loses focus (W3C model)

Comment: @RobG, you do not understand. We can navigate through the items of the select box, but you cannot instantly select the navigated item from it. So I wrote the hack below. Cheers.

Comment: You're right, I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

This was more easy than I tought, with jQuery of course:

```
$('#year').on('keyup', function() {
    $(this).change();
});
```

As [Xander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88932/xander) suggested, I just triggered the `.on('keyup')` event on top of the select box field, and on each change of the selected value of the select box it will automatically select it and I have the event working!

Thanks all others who helped.